# grub error systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0: not found

Tags: linux, debian, grub

i am running on a vps debian 9 stretch

```
master@vps726152:~$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=debian
```

I started to have errors after an update when I tried an autoremove (sorry it is in french)

```
master@vps726152:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
2 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Après cette opération, 0 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Paramétrage de linux-image-4.9.0-14-amd64 (4.9.246-2) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-14-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet linux-image-4.9.0-14-amd64 (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de linux-image-amd64 :
 linux-image-amd64 dépend de linux-image-4.9.0-14-amd64 ; cependant :
 Le paquet linux-image-4.9.0-14-amd64 n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet linux-image-amd64 (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I made some diggings and found this error could be related to a grub problem so I tried this command :

```
master@vps726152:~$ sudo update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0: not found
```

my grub conf looks like this :

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

So this line seems to be the cause of my troubles

```
systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0
```

But I do not know what to do next, I found nothing helpful so far...
Could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 5):

You should use variable to set kernel boot parameter:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
```